# Archive Manager error Message in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I get an error message from archive manager in ubuntu 12.04 when I try to run A Downloaded file called Biosagentplus_568.exe. Can someone help me?? I am a ubuntu newbie,

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are attempting to run a Windows executable on a non-windows filesystem. The BiosAgentPlus_568.exe is not capable of running under Linux, though it may work under Wine. If this is from [here](http://biosagentplus.com/), then you may need to add that to a USB Stick or CD (not sure if that is a self-extracting piece of software or not) and try booting using same.

Unless there is a reason to update the BIOS that is driving that demand, it is probably not worth the risk and effort. Your BIOS should generally only be updated when required, or when there is some compelling reason to do so (some functionality added that is available to you, etc.).

If you are not familiar with updating BIOS and the risk, probably not worth the risk, as a failed BIO update is worse than no BIOS update. Proceed with caution.